# Exchange 2007: How can I tell which connections are Outlook Anywhere?

Tags: exchange-2007

I'm curious as to how many active Outlook Anywhere (RPC over HTTPS) connections a server has active vs. normal RPC connections.

I've looked through the results out of the get-logonstatistics commandlet and none of the fields seem to show what connection type is in use.

Can an Exchange 2007 distinguish between these connection types and if so what commands are available to pull that data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst you set-up Outlook Anywhere from the Exchange console, it's actually using the RPC proxy feature, which is separate to Exchange. Exchange doesn't actually care where the RPC connection comes from, whether its local or over http, as they all look the same when they get to Exchange, the RPC proxy and IIS handle the incoming traffic and forward it to Exchange.

To get some statistics on how many RPC users you have your going to have to look at the IIS logs. There is a good article [here](http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:6lgGdoMZ1u4J:msexchangeteam.com/archive/2007/09/12/446982.aspx+rpc+proxy+exchange+2007+statistics&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=firefox-a) on using Log parser to get these kind of statistics.

For example, getting the RPC statistics would look like this:

```
logparser "SELECT cs-username, Count(*) AS RPCProxyHits from c:\windows\system32
\logfiles\w3svc1\ex*.log WHERE cs-uri-stem LIKE '%rpcproxy.dll%' AND cs-username IS NOT 
NULL GROUP BY cs-username ORDER BY RpcProxyHits Desc" -rtp:-1
```

Comment: ok, as for the log parser, does it needs to be installed on the CAS server or in the workstation laptop ?